# Retain view bounds of dynamically added textview on fragment reload

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is a Fragment named FragmentA that has a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` behind it. (Say 4)Textviews are dynamically added to the `rlParentView` This layout resides inside a Fragment layout.

The `Textviews` are draggable inside the parent layout.

Another Fragment is loaded in the same activity and when FragmentA is reloaded, now the dynamically added textviews are lost so how can I retain the dynamically added TextViews with their text and other bounds.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/rlParentView">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dragable `TextView` are added dynamically like this:

```
View inflateLayout=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_drag_layout,mParentContainer,false);
TextView draggableView= (TextView) inflateLayout.findViewById(R.id.draggableView);

rlParentView.addView(inflateLayout);

draggableView.setText(Some_Text_here);

OnDragTouchListener listener=new OnDragTouchListener(draggableView, rlParentView,
        new OnDragTouchListener.OnDragActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDragStart(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDragEnd(View view) {

            }
        }
);

draggableView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but here's an idea:

In `onSaveInstanceState()` of *Fragment A*, save the positions (and whetever else) of the `TextView`s inside their parent. Something like:

```
class ViewPositionInfo implements Serializable {

    String text;
    int xPositionInParent;
    int yPositionInParent;
    // ... other variables you need to store
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    List<ViewPositionInfo> positionInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    // iterate over the views and add them inside the list

    outState.putExtra("positions", positionInfos);
}
```

Then, when the fragment is re-created, read this information in `onCreateView()`, create `TextView`s with those attributes and add them to the parent layout.

---

The solution above has a drawback. When rotating the screen, the width / height will be different than before, so saving x and y positions of the the text views inside their parent might not be a good idea. You might need to save a relative position, i.e. a percentage. But first things first - make the simple case work (as explained above) and then think about this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot I already had this idea in my mind and tried it, it works now.Could you please elaborate on this part now ? =.>`When rotating the screen, the width / height will be different than before, so saving x and y positions of the the text views inside their parent might not be a good idea. You might need to save a relative position, i.e. a percentage.`

Comment: @BatCat Let's say your screen's resolution is 1080x1920 (in portrait mode) and a `TextView` was at the bottom left of it - at (0, 1800). When you rotate the screen and it becomes landscape (1920x1080), the `TextView` will be **below** the screen! So that's why I said that maybe you save the relative position inside the parent, e.g. 50% of width and 32% of height. You can do other things instead, e.g. move those that are now outside the screen at the edge - it depends on how you want the behavior to be. I hope this is clear. Finally, could you please accept the answer if it helped you?